# Equivalence between two definitions of tangent vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be an $n-$dimensional smooth manifold. Usually, a tangent vector at $p \in M$ is defined as function $V$ from $C^{\infty}(M) $ to $\mathbb R$ satisfying the following properties(linear derivation):

1. $V(f+g)=V(f) + V(g)$.
2. $V(\alpha f)= \alpha V(F)$.
3. $V(fg) = V(f)g(p) + V(g)f(p)$.

However, in Hirsch's differential topology, a tangent vector to $M$ is an equivalence class $[x,i,a]$ of triples $(x,i,a)\in M\times \Lambda \times \mathbb R^n$ where $\lambda$ is the index set for charts $(U_i,\phi_i)$, under the equivalence relation:
$$[x,i,a]=[y,j,b]$$ if and only if $x=y$ and 
$$D(\phi_j \phi_i^{-1})(\phi_i(x))a=b.$$

How to prove these two definitions are equivalent, if they indeed are?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146901/equivalence-of-definitions-of-tangent-space